# Laravel redirect inside of middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a middleware check by login, how many games has the user, I want to show  another view if user have more than one game, but I got everytime redirect error if user has more than one:

This is in case `$assigned_games > 1`

```
$games = Auth::user()->userGames;
$assigned_games = count($games);

if ($assigned_games == 1) {
    return $next($request);
} elseif ($assigned_games > 1) {
    return redirect()->route('games.board');
} elseif ($assigned_games < 1) {
    echo "no game bought";
    exit;
}
```

I tried also only with `return route('games.board')` but it don't work.

How can I set correct redirect here?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin "redirected you too many times."

Comment: code is correct but make sure the route games.board doesn't use this middleware because if games.board route use that middleware it will go in redirect loop so the route you are redirecting should not again redirect.

Comment: @Sam yes, it is inside, is it possible to create there a exception?

Comment: you should throw the exception in middleware because middleware is executed first and then controller method is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if both your route is inside middleware then you should check the current route and if its same as you are redirecting you shouldn't redirect to avoid redirect loop

```
$games = Auth::user()->userGames;
$assigned_games = count($games);

if ($assigned_games == 1) {
    return $next($request);
} elseif ($assigned_games > 1 && \Route::currentRouteName() != 'games.board') {
    return redirect()->route('games.board');
} elseif ($assigned_games < 1) {
    echo "no game bought";
    exit;
} else {
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: it works, but now I have always redirect to this page, it is possible to limitate this request only by login?

Comment: add auth middleware before this middleware in your route. so for ex.
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'yourmiddleware']], function(){});

and then it will go in your middleware only after logged in.